# Insert record to a table using linq query that contains auto increment ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having issue to insert a record to table that contains auto increment ID ,

I'm going to insert values to table using entity frameworks.

This is my table creation query

```
USE [DB_Name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name](
    [Discussion_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Discussion_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Discription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Discussion_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

This is my View Page code

```
@model albaraka.Models.Table_Name

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Discussion_Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Discussion_Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AB_Discussion</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Discussion_ID)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discussion_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discussion_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discussion_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Discription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

this is model class

```
namespace project_name.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Table_Name
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
        public int Discussion_ID { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_Name { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is controller class

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Discussion_Create()
{         
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Discussion_Create(Table_Name discussion)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Table_Name.Add(discussion);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(discussion);
}
```

I want to insert record without user enter discussion Id, that's why I put it in a hidden field here, how can I do that?

Comment: There is no need to hide it, just leave it on zero and do the add. So remove the hidden element and test. Put the savechanges in a try catch block so you can see if anything goes wrong.

Comment: cannot understand exactly what youre saying,can you mention the syntax

Comment: @Chathz Your code should work as it is. Philip is suggesting removing the `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Discussion_ID)` as it does nothing. But either way, it should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: since Im not entering value for Discussion_ID using front end my model state is invalid there for I cannot insert values

Comment: It will be 0, the framework will initialise it.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors with your code?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck ohhh thats worked thnks lot

Comment: @Rob as you said its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use any hidden element in your view, you can remove it.
You should use a try catch block in your save changes do you can catch EF exceptions and act accordingly :

```
try{
    db.Table_Name.Add(discussion);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception Ex){
    //trace the exception
}
```

put a breakpoint in the debugger on the exceptions if there is any and also peek in the db what is actually inserted.
I think your code should work, so i don anticipate exceptions but it is good practice to check for them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign value to the Identity column. its meaningless.All you need to do is insert records using  linq To Entity

```
 var yourTable= new TablName{ Discussion_Name = "Discussion1",Discription ="Some Description" };

 var db = new YourEFContext();

 db.Table_Name.Add(yourTable);

 db.SaveChanges();
```

The Framework will initialise the value to 0